# Display list from database using linq in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm really new to vb and linq, so I'm sorry if what I have is completely wrong.. I have a page that is the detail view of a project. In it, I want to display a list of all the linked projects. This is what I have.. (which I'm guessing is very wrong)

```
Private Sub divLinks_OnLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbLinks.DataBinding
    Dim Link1 = (From a In ods.groups
                 Where (a.PID = PID_Number)
                 Select a).ToList

    dvLinks = Link1.Text 
End Sub
```

I'm not even sure if I'm supposed to put the code behind my div or a lisbox or something. I'm sure this is super simple I'm just brain dead right now I guess...

EDIT

I tried this, no errors but still not returning anything

```
Private Sub dvLinks_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dvLinks.Load
    Call LoadLinks()
End Sub

Public Function LoadLinks()
    Dim Link1 = (From a In ods.groups
  Where (a.PID = PID_Number)
  Select a).ToList

    Return Link1.Count

End Function
```

Comment: Slowly. `Link1` its object of `List(Of T)` type, There is no property named `Text`. But it has a property (actualy function, not property) named `Count`, for example. so try write: `dvLinks = Link1.Count`. That way we will know if the DB query worked.

Comment: Excellent. The error message takes us far. she says we are trying to put a number `HtmlGenericControl` type variable. by Google I find on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) that this object has many properties, such as `InnerText`. Try to put the number in there, like this: `dvLinks.InnerText = Link1.Count`

Comment: Great! That worked...it displayed the number 2 (and there are only two things that fit the query) What's the next step to have it list them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through the list in a loop (and in fact, therefore, you do not need to export by "ToList").

For example:

```
Private Sub dvLinks_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dvLinks.Load
    Dim Link1 = From a In ods.groups
                Where (a.PID = PID_Number)
                Select a

    For Each group In Link1
        dvLinks.InnerText += group 
    End For
End Sub
```

*I assume the translation of the Group to a string (actually by the method ToString) returns something "interesting". If not, you can access the property like: `group.Name`*

This is for simplicity, but in terms of performance it is not recommended to concatenate a string over and over again (it is created anew each time in a different place in memory). It is best to write by LINQ Like this:

```
    Dim Link1 = From a In ods.groups
                Where (a.PID = PID_Number)
                Select a.ToString()

    dvLinks.InnerText = String.Join("<br/>", Link1.ToArray())
```

(it takes a little while to figure out but not too hard).